# Match-no-documents Query object in Lucene

Tags: java, lucene

How do I create a new `Query` instance having the property of not matching any document, analogous to the [MatchAllDocsQuery](https://lucene.apache.org/core/4_6_0/core/org/apache/lucene/search/MatchAllDocsQuery.html), but opposite?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A Boolean query without any clause returns no documents.

`Query blank = new BooleanQuery();`

Answer (score 0):

For newer versions of Lucene you can use the Builder with the same result.

Query blank = new BooleanQuery.Builder().build();